# If there is one instance of a class with variable=x

Tags: java

What I want to do is to check if at least one of the several instances of class Dude (for example) has a certain value for a certain variable, say

```
public boolean isFat(Dude d) {
    // checks weight and returns boolean
}

...

for (i = 0; i < DudeList.size(); i++) {
    if (isFat(DudeList.get(i)) {
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

`DudeList` would be a static `ArrayList` reference in `Dude` which adds a `Dude` instance with every constructor, I think you know the trick.

But I was wondering if there's an easier way? This just seems kind of sloppy. Because I might as well have 138174917 Dude instances and only one or two are Fat

Comment: Well you could separate the two categories out, keeping a list for fat dudes and a list for not-fat dudes (I think your example is in fairly poor taste, by the way - I'm sure you could come up with a more sensible one). But we don't know whether that would be a problem for other reasons. Really we don't have enough context to answer. I would suggest that using static fields like this is rarely a good idea.

Comment: If there are 138174917 dudes, you will have to check each and every one to know, you could separate them in the constructor/changing weight

Comment: I think you should explain what you are trying to achieve so we can suggest better way of doing it.  As many people have said, this smells like a really bad approach.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah; I missed that closing bracket.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to iterate like this, then probably the best thing to do is carry an external count of those classes that are "fat".  Normally you would do this a static variable in the class and you should increment the count in the setter for that variable.

```
public class Dude{
    static int nFats = 0;

    public void setFat(){
        Dude.nFats++;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to be safer (and probably more correct in this case) you could also use an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) which is specifically designed for threadsafe counters.

Comment: Uhm, `AtomicInteger`? Also, no need for the `Dude` classifier, but that's a matter of style I guess

Comment: @fge. I had excluded the AtomicInteger for simplicity but I added that in for a more complete answer.  As for the Dude classifier, I just think it's a clearer way to set static variables (especially after having not seen the code for a while).

Comment: Well, what I wanted to know was if there is a built-in method that'll let me just pick the ´Dudes´ that are ´Fat´ without checking every other ´Dude´ instance. I would indeed need the ArrayList and not just a primitive because I will have to call a method on the ´Fat Dudes´.
Thanks anyway. I guess the method I wanted just doesn't exist...

Comment: Reasonable idea.  The issue with this approach is that if the Dude goes on a diet, you need to decrement Dude.nFats.  If a Dude is on a binge diet, then goes and pigs out on beer and pizza, you'll need to decrement then increment.  Depending on usage, it might be easiest to just iterate the list.

Comment: @user949300 as long as the variable is modified through getters/setters then there should be a max of 2, maybe 3 methods to increment/decrement the variable.

Comment: @MrFunky, yeah there is no method that will just give you a variable count. This method approach though is very simple and efficient.